# Visual Studio Emulator for Android not showing in list

Tags: xamarin, android-emulator, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin. I also Installed [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/).

Now, in my `Xamarin.Forms` project I do not see the installed emulator, only the Google's emulator.

[image: VS Start]

I can launch the emulator from the Start menu, but how can I make it visible to Visual Studio?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to open Visual Studio Emulators for Android and download at least one emulator before any hyper-v emulators will show in the list of emulators.

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/

Comment: Thanks Ken. I had to install and also start the emulator for it to be visible in Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to start the emulator directly from debug start instead of launching the emulator first?